# Would it be possible to de-orbit a small object by throwing it with human strength?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, deorbit

If an astronaut went on a spacewalk (say from the ISS), tethered him/herself to a relatively massive object in orbit around the earth (say the ISS), and threw a small object in the direction opposite to the massive object's orbit ('backwards'), would that be enough to de-orbit that small object?

Or would the small object only go on a new different orbit?

What if the astronaut throws the object towards the earth instead?

The small object would be the size of a baseball/tennis ball, of any material.

Please do not take initial atmospheric drag into account.
The question might be better phrased as - would the object de-orbit substantially faster/earlier than the massive object?

Comment: These are related, but not necessarily the same question [How hard do you have to throw something off the ISS to make it deorbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28002/12102) as well as [How long does trash jettisoned by hand from the ISS fall before burning up on reentry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25939/12102) and also [Was this large pieces of “space junk” just released from the ISS in the “nadir and retrograde” direction?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24749/12102)...

Comment: ...and finally [What are the orbital mechanical consideration behind hand-launched nanosatellites from the ISS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22732/12102)

Comment: @uhoh that is what I was looking for thank you